# Select values from different rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table (TABLE) which contains rows.

I want a query to pick different value from different rows when the column: LIBELLE is repeated.

EX :

```
LIBELLE  DEBIT  CREDIT   DATE
LIB1     500     NULL  15/04/2019
LIB1     NULL    NULL  15/04/2019
LIB1     NULL    20    15/04/2019
LIB2     100     NULL  16/04/2019
LIB2     NULL    NULL  16/04/2019
LIB2     NULL    150   16/04/2019
```

Expected result :

```
LIBELLE  DEBIT  CREDIT    DATE
LIB1     500      20   15/04/2019
LIB2     100      15   16/04/2019
```

So from the first row, i want to pick value of debit, & value of CREDIT from the 3rd row.

Comment: Could you please show us your code and let us know where you are having trouble?

Comment: you must have some `id` column in your table to get your first and last row respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Try using GROUP BY, note it isn't clear whether you should select the same Libelle across dates or for one date:

For duplicates for each date

```
   SELECT Libelle, SUM(Debit) As Debit, SUM(Credit) As Credit, Date
    FROM TABLE
    GROUP BY Libelle, Date
```

For duplicates across dates

```
   SELECT Libelle, SUM(Debit) As Debit, SUM(Credit) As Credit, MAX(Date) As Date
    FROM TABLE
    GROUP BY Libelle, Date
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this...

If you want first debit and last credit, as per your shared case rest of the values are null.

```
  select distinct Libelle, max(isnull(debit,0)) as Debit, max(isnull(credit,0)) as Credit , Date from table group by Libelle, date
```

If you want the sum of all debit and credit for each date

```
 select distinct Libelle, sum(isnull(debit,0)) as Debit, sum(Isnull(credit,0)) as Credit, date from table group by Libelle, date
```

Not very good code but works for you, for case of taking only debit from first row and credit from last row.

```
 ; with cte as ( select row_number() over (partition by Libelle order by date,(select 100)) as Slno, Libelle, isnull(debit,0) as debit, isnull(credit,0) as credit, date from table )
 select c.Libelle , c.debit, t.credit, c.date from 
 (select top 1 * from cte order by slno) as c 
 inner join (select top 1 * from cte order by slno desc) as t on c.date=t.date and c.Libelle=t.Libelle
```

BTW, don't you have an Id column in table to get your first and last value 
if yes then replace `select 100` with that column name.

Answer (score 0):

you can use sub-query as well to get the output:-

```
 SELECT t.libelle,
         (SELECT t1.debit FROM table t1
           WHERE t1.libelle = t.libelleAND debitIS NOT NULL) debit,
         (SELECT t2.credit FROM table t2
           WHERE t2.libelle = t.libelleAND creditIS NOT NULL) credit,
         t.date
    FROM table t
   GROUP BY t.libelle, t.date;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

```
select Libelle,
       max(Debit),
       max(Credit),
       max(Date)
from TABLE
```

I would discourage from using `sum` as it would return `null` because of the `null` in grouped columns.

`max` will return the only value which is not `null` (same with `min`).